# This website is not accessible

Tags: magento, accessible

When I open my website on mobile it is displaying an error message. 
[image]
But when I open it on my laptop it is opening well. My website is in magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue pertains to the Pakistani government enforcing limitations on access to information on the web. Your cellphone service provider probably has these limitations in place already whereas the ISP you are using for internet access on your notebook has not.

You can [view this article from back in 2013](http://www.ibtimes.com/blasphemous-contrary-islam-pakistan-bans-nations-first-gay-website-1411508) where a similar message was displayed.